# Unable to get associative array value?

Tags: javascript, associative-array

Not really sure what's happening here so some clarification would be appreciated.

I have an object that is created called DBstats, it holds values based on:

team (string) ==> {object of stats}

However when I try to get the object using the key with a variable, Im getting undefined but when I use a literal string value, It works just fine.

```
//populate the associative array, result is an object passed in as a parameter
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    DBstats[result[i].Team] = result[i];
}

var Team1str = "team1";
console.log(DBstats); //prints everything in the associative array, confirming string => object
console.log(DBstats["team1"]); //prints out object
console.log(DBstats[Team1str]);  //prints undefined???
```

What am I not understanding?

```
result array =
{
  team1: {team1.name, data... }
  team2: {team2.name,  data... }
  team3: {team3.name, data... } 
  team4: {team4.name,  data... }
  team5: {team5.name, data... } 
  team6: {team6.name,  data... }
  team7: {team7.name,  data... }
  team8: {team8.name,  data... }
  team9: {team9.name,  data... }

}
```

Comment: Seems odd, can you edit a [MCVE] into your question?

Comment: console.log(DBstats["team1"][0]);

Comment: @NickParsons, Sorry that was a typo

Comment: This is still not complete or verifiable.

Comment: I don't think I can add any more clarity, this is the problem in its simplest form.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem here using a code snippet?

Comment: Add the contents of the `result` array.

Comment: What does `console.log(Team1str == "team1")` show?

Comment: Either you're mistyping, or something is changing `Team1str` between the assignment and using it.

Comment: There's no difference between using a variable and a literal with the same value as the variable. So obviously the variable doesn't really contain what you think it does.

Comment: Hey, `result array =...` is not a valid JS. Try it in any JS environment, fix, and update the question! Also show what `DBstats` looks like.

Comment: That value is an object, not an array. It  looks like the value of `DBstats`, not `results`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there is so much messed up in your question, but I like this kind of questions (they are like puzzles).

So you probably want this:

```js
    const result = [
      {name: 'team1', data: {}},
      {name: 'team2', data: {}},
      {name: 'team3', data: {}},
    ]
    
    let DBstats = {}
    
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        DBstats[result[i].name] = result[i];
    }
    
    var Team1str = "team1";
    console.log(DBstats); //prints everything in the associative array, confirming string => object
    console.log(DBstats["team1"]); //prints out object
    console.log(DBstats[Team1str]);  //prints out object
```

1. You are probably from PHP world. And, no, there is no such term as "associative array" in JS. Instead, it is called "object".
2. I formatted your non-JS array `result` to actual JS syntax.
3. Everything works as expected (check it out yourself by pressing "Run code snippet")!

Comment: Apologies, the problem is too complex to just write the code out for.  Barmar suggestions of comparing the two is what led me to the solution. 

I had converted Team1str using JSON.Stringify(), and then used toUpperCase() to match what was in the Object. I used the term associative array in order to make myself clear. When comparing the types of Team1str and "team1", they both showed String, however Team1str == "team1" showed false.

I then used String(Team1str) and that ended up working. Im assuming they both showed String, however one was a JSON object string?

Comment: @user1234700 You should have posted all the transformations of `Team1str`. JSON.Stringify() gives just a string primitive. Probably there was some other thing that turned your Team1str to something other than "team1". Or even Team1str contained invisible character but that's a rare and exotic case.

Comment: @user1234700 Oh wait, so you've converted a string with `JSON.Stringify()`? Of course you will get `undefined`! Because `JSON.Stringify()` converts `'str'` to `'"str"'` (adds double quotes)!